# adding native-like splash factory in flutter buttons

Tags: flutter

i want to add a native-looking splash factory to my buttons in flutter (as you may know , buttons in android show a faster splash factory once they are tapped ).

heres how it looke know :
[flutter default splash factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOWuO.gif)
and how i want it to be :
[android native splash factory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgJOZ.gif)

i tried using **InkRipple.splashFactory**,**InkSplash.splashFactory** and **InkSparkle.splashFactory** , but they didnt make much diffrence. i expect to achieve that by editing flutter`s default splash factory duration.

Solved by changing these lines in ink_ripple.dart :

```
const Duration _kUnconfirmedRippleDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 250);
const Duration _kFadeInDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 75);
const Duration _kRadiusDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 100); 
const Duration _kFadeOutDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 375);
const Duration _kCancelDuration = Duration(milliseconds: 75);
```

Comment: check `material/ink_ripple.dart` / `material/ink_splash.dart` sources, notice how durations are defined in few top lines of both files

Comment: @pskink yea thanks. i think that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike React Native and few other hybrid frameworks which replaces it's widget code with it's corresponding Android/iOS widgets (Java/Swift code), Flutter has it's own engine rendering it's own widgets from Dart code to native code. (Except for web, it converts the dart code to Javascipt).

Hence You might find a lot of minor differences in the material and cupertino libraries not having similar look and feel as the Android and iOS SDK.

But Flutter does provide customizable options to fix it.

For example in case of Elevated Button :

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {}, child: null, style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(animationDuration: , foregroundColor: , backgroundColor: , surfaceTintColor: ))
```

You can use the above abstract ButtonStyle class (ElevatedButton.styleFrom) to change the animation duration and background, shadow, foreground colors etc. to make it look like it's native counterparts.

Comment: yes and you are right, but thats not what i meant.what @pskink suggested, fixed the problem.